# Angular component view layer not updating with localStorage changes without refresh

Tags: angular, local-storage, angular-services

I have two components utilizing the same service to get() and set() items to localStorage. One component sets()/'adds' items to localStorage

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import {Product} from '../product'; 
import { PRODUCTS } from '../mock-products'; 
import {CartService} from '../cart.service'; 

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cart-item',
  templateUrl: './cart-item.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./cart-item.component.css']
})

export class CartItemComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() cartItem: Product; 

  constructor(private cartService: CartService) { } 

  ngOnInit() { }


  addToCart() {  // adds item to localStorage

  this.closeModal();
  alert('item(s) successfully added to cart');


  const cart = [];
  const currentCart = this.cartService.get();
  if (currentCart != null && currentCart.length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < currentCart.length; i++) {
      cart.push(currentCart[i]);
    }
  }

   cart.push(this.cartItem);
   this.cartService.set(cart);

 }
}
```

and the other component gets() the data from localStorage displaying the data in a table.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, ChangeDetectionStrategy } from 
'@angular/core';
import { Product } from '../product'; // data types
import { PRODUCTS } from '../mock-products'; // database
import { CartService } from '../cart.service'; // service

@Component({
selector: 'app-checkout',
templateUrl: './checkout.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./checkout.component.css']
 })


 export class CheckoutComponent implements OnInit {
 shoppingCart: Product[]; 
 @Input() PRODUCTS: Product; 
 constructor(private cartService: CartService) {  this.shoppingCart = 
  this.cartService.get(); }

  ngOnInit() {}

  checkOut() {

  this.shoppingCart = this.cartService.get();
  console.log(this.shoppingCart); // service is working, changes are 
  not being reflected in HTML


  const span = document.getElementsByClassName('closeModal')[0];
  const modal = document.getElementById('shoppingCart'); // pulls up 
  modal
  modal.style.display = 'block';
   }
```

Within this same component I am able to make changes to localStorage and see realtime changes by running: this.cartService.get()

```
 deleteItem(id, shoppingCart) {
   const newCart = [];
   for (let i = 0; i < shoppingCart.length; i++) {
     if (shoppingCart[i].id !== id) {
       newCart.push(shoppingCart[i]);
     }
   }
this.cartService.set(newCart);
this.shoppingCart = this.cartService.get();
 }
```

}

I have console logged and new items are being set() to localStorage, the table just isn't updated with the new data unless refreshed.

Here is the HTML table that isn't updating, it uses *ngFor to loop over 'shoppingCart' and create the table:

```
<table id="shoppingCartTable" >
    <thead>
    <th> Item </th>
    <th> </th>
    <th> </th>
    <th> Price </th>
    <th> Quantity </th>
    <th> Total </th>
    <th> Delete? </th>
    <tr *ngFor="let cartItem of this.shoppingCart">
      <td>{{cartItem.productName}}</td>
      <td><img src={{cartItem.img}} /></td>
      <td>{{cartItem.description}}</td>
      <td>${{cartItem.price}}</td>
      <td>{{cartItem.quantity}}</td>
      <td>{{cartItem.price * cartItem.quantity}}</td>
      <td><button><img src="./assets/icons/trashcan.png" 
 (click)="deleteItem(cartItem.id, shoppingCart)" /></button></td>
  </tr>
    <tr>
     <button id="checkoutBtn"(click)="confirmCheckout()"> Checkout
     </button>
    </tr>

  </thead>

    <tbody id="tbodyCart"></tbody>
  </table>
```

Here is my service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './product'; // data model
import { PRODUCTS } from './mock-products'; // database +

@Injectable()
export class CartService {

 constructor() { }

 set(shoppingCart: Product[]) { 
   localStorage.setItem('shoppingCart', JSON.stringify(shoppingCart));
  }
 get() {
   return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('shoppingCart'));
   }


 }
```

I have tried using default ChangeDetectionStrategy as well as .OnPush, neither work. I have combed through stackoverflow and read about RxJs observables but haven't been able to apply/am not quite understanding how they work, not even sure that's the answer. How might I get my view layer to respond to changes in localStorage from another component without refreshing? I am new to Angular and would like an Angular solution, but any direction would be helpful!

Comment: why do you have confirmCheckout in your table but checkout method in the .ts file?either a typo or a method you forgot to show code.Have you also tried to remove the modal part of the checkout and see what happen?

Comment: confirmCheckout() is a different function not yet written within the CheckoutComponent. Really all checkOut() does is display/pull up the modal when a button is clicked within the HTML (I realize now I didn't include it above). If I remove the modal aspect then I won't be able to view the items within the 'cart' since that's where they live.

Comment: can you post a small https://stackblitz.com/ with the problem? stackblitz example of the problem greatly help us finding problem and solution in alot of case.Also there is no need for getDocumentById in angular with @ViewChild and mapping the html field with #id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
 shoppingCart: Product[];
```

To this:

```
 get shoppingCart(): Product[] {
   this.cartService.get();
 };
```

Then every time the built-in change detection picks up a change and the bindings are re-evaluated, the getter will be called and will get the current values.

I've not tried this technique with local storage ... but it works great with services so might work in this case as well.

Comment: that did the trick! Thank you! Here are the changes I made:                                 get shoppingCart( ): Product[ ] {
     const result = this.cartService.get();
     return result;
   }
  
  constructor(private cartService: CartService) { removed contents here }  and in my delete function I just called this.cartService.get( ) to have the table generate again once changes were made/items were deleted.

Comment: Great! If that solved it for you, can you mark this as your answer so the question can be closed? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the BEST way to do it, but in the CartService, before the constructor you could add a public variable named 'cart' for instance of type BehaviorSubject like so ...

```
cart: Subject<Product[]> = new BehaviorSubject<Product[]>(null);
```

then you would change the code in your cartService so that you update its cart variable by calling its 'next' function each time you change the shoppingCart contents

```
this.cart.next(shoppingCart);
```

this would allow you to 'subscribe' to any changes made to the cart variable wherever you use the cartService. Within your CheckoutComponent's ngOnInit() function for example you could write

```
this.cartService.cart.subscribe((newCart) => { this.shoppingCart = newCart });
```

the effects of this code would be that each time you update the contents of the shopping cart via the cartService, all the places you 'subscribed' to that cart variable would get updated. It is a little indirect as you are not directly subscribing to the contents in localStorage, but instead to a variable in the service that is responsible for handling those localStorage contents but it should do the trick. I'm interested in knowing if you find something more direct.