# Local storage value changed but not showing without refreshing page

Tags: angular, local-storage

I tried to update user profile. It updated successfully after updating I store the lastest data in local storage so user name and picture show on every page. When I updated the user detail local storage value changed as I called the function to update the value in local storage but to show the changes I have to refresh the page. I tried to use

```
    localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(res.data.user));
    this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
```

function but still same problem. Is there any way to reflect the changes as changed in local storage.

```
  getUserInfo() {
return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
```

}

Is there any way to refresh another component oninit() on form submit.

Comment: Where do you call getUserInfo()?

Comment: You might not be calling the function which is responsible to show the details in the page after being updated.

Comment: The function is on another component.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Angular component view layer not updating with localStorage changes without refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48553611/angular-component-view-layer-not-updating-with-localstorage-changes-without-refr)

Comment: I have change the way to update the navbar data and show it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have hit the other component function and it works for me.

```
export class useService {

  private _listners = new Subject<any>();

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  getUser(){
    const slug = `${environment.baseUrl}user/info`;
    return this.http.get<any>(slug);
  }

  listen(): Observable<any> {
    return this._listners.asObservable();
 }

  updateNavbarData() {
    this._listners.next();
  }
```

I have create a common service and in component one I import the common service and call the function like below

```
this.useService.updateNavbarData();
```

And in second component I import the common service and called the function in

```
constructor () { 
        this.userService.listen().subscribe(() => {
        this.setUserDetail();
  })
}

this.setUserDetail(){
this.user = this.authService.getUserInfo();
this.changeDetection.detectChanges();
```

}

Now it works for me. Thanks